# Uploaded avatar image not getting displayed in GitLab

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, gitlab, bitnami

On my gitlab config `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb`, I have only the following code un-commented.

```
external_url 'http://gitlab.mydomain.com:8888'
unicorn['worker_timeout'] = 6000
unicorn['port'] = 8888
web_server['external_users'] = ['www-data']
nginx['enable'] = false
ci_nginx['enable'] = false
```

Again reconfigured by running,

```
sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure
sudo gitlab-ctl restart
```

And configured virtual host for apache on `/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/httpd.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName gitlab.mydomain.com
DocumentRoot /opt/gitlab/

ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8888/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8888/

# Custom log file locations
ErrorLog /opt/bitnami/apache2/logs/gitlab_error.log
CustomLog /opt/bitnami/apache2/logs/gitlab_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

When I updated profile avatar, the file is getting uploaded on `/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public/uploads/user/avatar/2/avatar.png`

But the image is not getting displayed in web interface and the image location attached to interface is `http://gitlab.mydomain.com:8888/uploads/user/avatar/2/avatar.png`

I can directly access the avatar on `http://gitlab.mydomain.com/uploads/user/avatar/2/avatar.png`.

How can I mode_rewrite all the requests on port 8888 to not have the port number? Or any other solutions to fix this?

Comment: did you configure DNS? like  add a cname record for that subdomain?

Comment: i see a bitnami site now

Comment: @lxer yeah, me too but it's based on the hosted zone config. Now how to get gitlab over there? Any idea?

Comment: i dont know about your setup, but usually virtualhost-conf goes into /etc/apache2/sites-enabled ,

Comment: @lxer the location is correct only, I have doubt on the virtual host code. One of my sub-domain configured there to point nodejs app on port 8080 and it is working fine.

Comment: @lxer got it up by following this link http://paulshipley.id.au/blog/coding-tips/install-gitlab-on-ubuntu-14-04-using-apache2 but some proxy error shows `The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.`

Comment: Can you try with `external_url 'http://gitlab.mydomain.com'`? (as in http://serverfault.com/a/754614/783)

Comment: @VonC please post as detailed answer, it is working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in "[Gitlab and Apache - Uploaded images 404 errors](https://serverfault.com/a/754614/783)", you don't need to specify the port in `external_url`.

In your case, that would be:

```
external_url 'http://gitlab.mydomain.com'
```

Then the url displayed would *consistently* be `http://gitlab.mydomain.com`, not `http://gitlab.mydomain.com:8888`.